# Is there a way to filter the coordinates within a state/province/city/district only using the Haversine formula?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have already implemented the Google map javascript api where I store a list of location specified by users by storing their lat, lng, placeId into the database. So users can find places that is within a radius of a place in km/mile.

I am using the Haversine formula based on this Google map tutorial https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/store-locator/clothing-store-locator

My issue is I want to limit the coordinates return from sql query that is restricted to within a state (or city or district) too, because if a user put the point near a state border, the Haversine formula can potentially return coordinates from other state too, which is not what I want. I have been researching about this for sometime, it seem that the way to achieve this is to store the state information into the database too, am I correct ?

Or any better way of achieving this via Google map javascript API ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as you are storing your users location in your database, you should also have a table with your administrative subdivisions. (For example, states, which you can get freely at [ESRI OpenData](https://hub.arcgis.com/datasets/8cfeebda1d9d40f4bb03a6f5686e54b6_4)).

So, if you followed the tutorial you mentioned, I'd have to guess you're using MySQL, and you have your points stored as records with a `lat` and `lng` fields. Good enough to display them on the map, but not good enough to use spatial intersections.

The geometry of your stores would have to be constructed using [ST_GeomFromText()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-wkt-functions.html#function_st-geomfromtext). for example

```
SELECT 
  ST_GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(', lng, ' ', lat, ')' )) as markerposition
FROM markers;
```

Then, if you had a table of the US States, named "us_states" and this table had a `geom` field of type `geometry`, you could use the [ST_Contains](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-contains) function to get all the markers contained within a given state geometry (in the following example, contained in california):

```
SELECT * FROM markers
JOIN us_states ON ST_Contains(us_states.geom, ST_GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(', markers.lng, ' ', markers.lat, ')' )))
WHERE us_states.name='California';
```

Now, I'd say that's the proper way. But if it's too far fetched for what you want to achieve, you can also do this in the front. If you had a `google.maps.Polygon` representing the geometry of a state, you could use
the [google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#poly) method to filter which markers to show, or which markers to hide if they fall outside of said polygon. Something like

```
if (!google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(marker.getPosition(), statePolygon)) {
  marker.setMap(null);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the great answer. Previously, I was wondering if there's a Google Map Api function which I don't know that allow me to throw in a bunch of coordinates and also a state/country then give me back those coordinates that is within those state/country, so now I know I have to keep track those state/country by myself. Hence, I asked before I implement this. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, you have to provide the administrative subdivision yourself, either in the back or in the frontend

Comment: Hi do I go about obtaining a list of US States geometry?

Comment: Just look for "US States geojson" or "US counties geojson", there's plenty on repos out there now that github display geojson as maps. https://github.com/shawnbot/topogram/blob/master/data/us-states.geojson